# NSString initWithBytes with openssl encrypted data returns nil with NSUTF8StringEncoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, nsstring, openssl

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to create an NSString from encrypted data created by OpenSSL and I keep getting nil for the string.

The code that I'm using to encrypt and decrypt the data is taken from the following link http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt

Now here is the code where I'm calling to encrypt my data ("aes_init" is of course called on my application init):

```
//-- encrypt saved data
int textLen = str.size();
char* buff = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());

EVP_CIPHER_CTX encryptCtx;
unsigned char *ciphertext = aes_encrypt(&encryptCtx,
                                    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buff),
                                    &textLen);

NSString * nsstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ciphertext)
                                    length:strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ciphertext))
                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[nsstring autorelease];

UIApplication* clientApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
AppController* appController = ((AppController *)clientApp.delegate);
[appController saveData:nsstring]; //--> crash at this line
```

I've tried different Encoding (NSASCIIStringEncoding and NSUnicodeStringEncoding) and they don't crash but the data is completely wrong after I decode.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Ciphertext, the output of an encryption function, *should* be indistinguishable from random. Meaning that any byte value can be generated, including byte values that do not map to characters. Hence it is needed to **encode** the ciphertext, for instance using base 64 encoding.

Comment: I'm very new at objective-c so how would I do that?